# Am I compelled to put everything on one single page when adding a scroll effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm kinda stuck. I have to create a portfolio and I have to mostly use html5 and css3, with a bit of js, jquery and stuff if I really want to. I'm not very good at web development but I still wanted to experiment and do a professional and nice site. The thing is, implementing a simple scroll effect on your whole website seems to force you to write the html code on one single index. Does anyone know if this is really the case? Are there other solutions?
Thanks in advance. I know that it is not the smartest question but I'm really not good at it, so sorry in advance. Bye!

(I didn't really try anything yet except from the classic class "scroll-container", which is my main problem : I still want to have several html pages to separate things so that it is clear in my mind. Putting everything on a single webpage will definitely lose me)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+lazy+scroll+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: What exactly is the "scroll effect" that you have in mind? Can you update your question to include a [mre] in the form of a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/438273) to demonsrate?

Answer (score -1):

use an external library or plugin, such as fullPage.js or Scrollify, which can enable a scroll effect across multiple pages.